# Why am I asked for the "password for root" when upgrading packages?

Tags: 12.04, root, permissions

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. I installed with one user account, then added a second user account using the GUI dialog box method, making myself an Administrator type.

I now use the second user account.  When using update manager and it needs to add or remove packages, it asks me for the "password for root" rather than my own password.  I've installed and used a lot of Ubuntu systems and never been asked for the root password before.  I know how to set a root password so I can work around this situation.  sudo works fine and I'm very comfortable on the command line, so I can do everything I need to.

But I want to understand why my account is not allowed to authorise upgrades etc using the GUI.

I have checked the groups and added my account to all that the installuser has.

```
$ groups
hamish adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ groups installuser
installuser : installuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

#### Edit

```
$ id
uid=1001(hamish) gid=1001(hamish) groups=1001(hamish),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),114(netdev),126(sambashare),130(vboxusers)
$ id installuser
uid=1000(installuser) gid=1000(installuser) groups=1000(installuser),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),126(sambashare)

$ sudo tree /var/lib/polkit-1
/var/lib/polkit-1
└── localauthority
    ├── 10-vendor.d
    │   └── com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
    ├── 20-org.d
    ├── 30-site.d
    ├── 50-local.d
    └── 90-mandatory.d

$ sudo grep -A 3 Update /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes
```

As you can see from the tree command above, there are no other files under `/var/lib/polkit-1` to override `com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`.  I haven't edited that file either.  Does this mean I should be in the `admin` group as well as the `sudo` group?  Or should being in one group be enough?

What else should I look at?

#### Edit 2

Just checked and there is no `admin` group in `/etc/group` - is that unusual?  Should I add that group and then add myself to that group?

(Apparently not - see comment below by @Eric Carvalho)

#### Edit 3

```
$ gconftool -g /apps/gksu/sudo-mode
true
```

Comment: Please you update you answer with: 1) result of `id` command; 2) the output of the section `[Update already installed software]` of file `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` (note: you will need sudo permission to read that file). I have 12.04.02 with 2 users and have never been asked for root pw.

Comment: @Salem: I've added the information you asked for.

Comment: See my answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/257732

Comment: @aquaherd: checked and all those processes are running.

Comment: From [Ubuntu 12.04 Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop): _Up until Ubuntu 11.10, administrator access using the sudo tool was granted via the "admin" Unix group. In Ubuntu 12.04, administrator access will be granted via the "sudo" group. This makes Ubuntu more consistent with the upstream implementation and Debian. For compatibility purposes, the "admin" group will continue to provide sudo/administrator access in 12.04._

Comment: Hamish, what is the result of typing ``gconftool -g /apps/gksu/sudo-mode`` into a terminal as the user you are trying to debug?

Comment: @AaronD: the output is `true` - also added this to the main question.