# policykit-desktop-privilege - rules not in effect

Tags: xubuntu, privileges, policykit

my xubuntu installation asks me for my password everytime I try to mount/umount/update software ... all the things that policykit-desktop-privilege should grant me. The user is in both admin and sudo group and I think the necessary packages are installed:

```
i A policykit-1                     - framework for managing administrative poli
i A policykit-1-gnome               - GNOME-Authentifizierungsagent für PolicyKi
i   policykit-desktop-privileges    - run common desktop actions without passwor
i A libpolkit-agent-1-0             - Authentifizierungsagent-API für PolicyKit 
i A libpolkit-backend-1-0           - PolicyKit backend API                     
i A libpolkit-gobject-1-0           - PolicyKit Authorization API               
i A libpolkit-qt-1-1                - PolicyKit-qt-1 library
```

has anyone tips on this?

Comment: Installing updates in Linux usually requires a password - perfectly normal and standard behavior. Hope you'll get used to it. Mounting and unmouning partitions depen on how you do it. Use `udisks`, it shouldn't need passwords.

Comment: Upvoted from -1 to 0. Applying updates to already installed software and mounting internal and external drives does NOT require   a password when `policykit-desktop-privileges` is installed, at least for gnome based desktops.

Comment: I understand that changing the system needs more rights than a 'normal' user has - my problem is that policykit and policykit-desktop-privilege, which should grant me these rights, seem not to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In the ubuntu desktop privileges, file `com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`, this caught my attention:

```
[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-*;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-ata-smart*;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-system;org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab;
ResultActive=yes
```

And for software:

```
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes
```

- You will need to check if the policykit agent is running, e.g. `pgrep -lf polkit` from the command line. Same applies to *udisk*, *udev* and *gvfs*.
- Any upgrade will work unless there are new packages thrown in or packages obsoleted by changed dependencies, e.g. new kernels. In this case, you will need the `org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages` privilege, which you can add in the same manner as ubuntu did. There are more privileges which can be seen with `grep "<action id=" /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy` from the command line.
- This is just the same as in regular ubuntu, not xubuntu-specific. Maybe there is a slight difference between *xfce* and *xubuntu sessions* during login when you upgraded from previous versions of xubuntu where still *hal* was used over *udev*.

Comment: polkit-agent, udisk, udev and gvfs seem to be running - see [here](http://pastebin.com/1mzkq8S6)